# Should I convert my ObjC app to Swift if my App is going to be in for the long run?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I was wondering what everyone's belief about this. I am not sure if it is recommended to do this or not.

Comment: Swift has a long way to go before it stabilizes.  And there are millions of lines of code in Objective-C that aren't going to be abandoned any time soon -- Apple would get *a lot* of pushback if it attempted to "deprecate" Objective-C.

Comment: It's not unheard of for Apple to deprecate old tools. It's going to take a while with obj-c, but I doubt that obj-c will be in use by apple in ~10 years. Obj-c was not used before Mac OS X either.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it is hard to say what will happen in the future. But one can assume that Swift will be widely accepted and all API's onward shall be written in it. In that case I would recommend "encapsulating" all of the logic that is now written in Objective-C and use is AS-IS. All of the UI and new stuff I'd recommend writing in Swift.

It is fairly normal, especially in the banking sector that the internals are written in COBOL with multiple layers above it. It works but it's not ZEN-like for the developers to make some deep changes.